# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug' while using Google Pubsub Client Library

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am getting the following error when I try to run the application:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Here is the Build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.manzoor.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
    android.packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        exclude 'META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties'
        exclude 'com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite'

    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile group: 'com.google.cloud', name: 'google-cloud-pubsub', version: '0.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

}
```

Comment: Could you post more details of the error message? It's not clear at this point what could be going on.